# How to save a highchart to PNG image in R?

Tags: r, plot, highcharts, save, export

How to export a highchart (type = 'organization') to PNG image in R?

Here is an example:

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'organization') %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = list(
      list(from = 'A', to = 'A1'),
      list(from = 'A', to = 'A2')
    ))
```

[image]

I tried as follows, but the exported file is empty:

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

png("org.png")

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'organization') %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = list(
      list(from = 'A', to = 'A1'),
      list(from = 'A', to = 'A2')
    ))

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package [webshot](https://wch.github.io/webshot/articles/intro.html) to achieve that. Read more about on [Export highchart widget as figure in R](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/186).

**EDIT**: The answer worked for the OP using [webshot2](https://github.com/rstudio/webshot2), which is meant to replace webshot.

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)
library(webshot)


org <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'organization') %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = list(
      list(from = 'A', to = 'A1'),
      list(from = 'A', to = 'A2')
    ))

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(widget = org, file = "org.html")
getwd()
webshot(url = "org.html", 
        file = "org.png",
        delay=3) # delay will ensure that the whole plot appears in the image
dev.off()
```

Comment: It worked for html file. The png file is still empty. Would you have any other suggestions for saving the png file?

Comment: That is weird. Webshot takes a snapshot of the url, so it should work. So not even the example above works for you? I mean, with the example data? You could try to increase `delay`. Delay is ["Time to wait before taking screenshot, in seconds. Sometimes a longer delay is needed for all assets to display properly."](https://wch.github.io/webshot/reference/webshot.html).  You could also try to use `debug = TRUE` and see if you catch any issues there.

Comment: Even the example above is not working. The "org.png" file is generated, but when opening this file it does not show any image, it is empty. It also didn’t work to increase the delay.  Does the example work for you?

Comment: Yes, the example works for me. If I use the standard delay of the function, the png is saved missing part of the image.

Comment: You could try perhaps [webshot2](https://github.com/rstudio/webshot2). Good luck, and please let me know what the issue was when you find out!

Comment: Now it worked using the same code, but with the 'webshot2' package! Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! You're welcome. I will then add up webshot2 to the answer.